# Insert Image from an URL inside a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I would like to know if it is possible to load an image inside a ListView directly from the web, when the URL is stocked inside a json.

Edit : Solved, It is possible to use an AsyncTask

```
    public class ParseImage extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Drawable> {

        private ProgressBar pd;
        private ImageView imv;
        private int position;

        public ParseImage(int position, ImageView imv, ProgressBar pd2) {

            this.position = position;
            this.imv = imv;
            this.pd = pd2;

        }

        @Override
        public Drawable doInBackground(Object... params) {

            Drawable d = null;

            try {
                d = Drawable.createFromStream(
                        (InputStream) new URL(list.get(position).get("Cover"))
                                .getContent(), "src");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return d;

        }

        public void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {

            if (result != null && imv != null) {
                pd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                imv.setImageDrawable(result);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't perform network operations on UI Thread and use Universal Image Downloader to download images

Comment: The network operation on the UI Thread is just for the test, once the problem will be fixed, I'm gonna use asynctask with progressbar and all what is needed. Is there a native way to display the images ?

Comment: use Universal image downloader as I have mention in the above comment.. Search in google about the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own custom Listview to show more than a String.Here is a piece of code you can refer:

MovieAdaptor.java:

```
public class MovieAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList = new ArrayList<Movie>();


public MovieAdaptor(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, movies);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.movieArrayList = movies;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ContactHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ContactHolder();
        holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageThumbnail);
        holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.MovieTitle);
        holder.synopsis = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.synopsis);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    holder.title.setText(movieArrayList.get(position).title);
    holder.synopsis.setText(movieArrayList.get(position).synopsis);

       newAsyncDownloadImage(holder.thumbnail).execute(movieArrayList.get(position).posters.get("thumbnail"));


    return row;
}

static class ContactHolder {
    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView title;
    TextView synopsis;
}


}
```

Activity.class:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    moviesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_movies);
    moviesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position > HEADER) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MovieActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(MOVIE_OBJECT, movieArrayList.get(position - 1));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_row_header, null);
    moviesListView.addHeaderView(header);
    movieAdaptor = new MovieAdaptor(this, R.layout.listview_row_item, movieArrayList);
    moviesListView.setAdapter(movieAdaptor);
```

AsyncDownloadImage.java:

```
public class AsyncDownloadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
ImageView iv;
private HttpURLConnection connection;
private InputStream is;
private Bitmap bitmap;

public AsyncDownloadImage(ImageView mImageView) {
    iv = mImageView;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL((String) params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        is = connection.getInputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (null != result) {
        iv.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) result);
    } else {
        iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the return of

```
JSONfunction.getJSONfromURL("http://colmarmagazine.ctai.fr/issues.php");
```

Please ?
I think it's a bad parting ! Because you have :

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/colmarmagazine.ctai.fr/content/numerodemo/numerodemo.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

and a "/" too much in the url for your cover !

Comment: Please send me the log of this : Log.d("Json", json.toString());